# This Declaration has no store class -> encounter problem while using bool in classes cpp problem

Tags: c++, oop

i was working on a college Project and encountered this problem ->
When I declare the bool a and store value true/false in it, code runs fine
but while I only declare, and stores the value afterwards, like in code, it shows an error, can anyone explain why it is...?

```
#include <iostream>

class Design{
    public:
    void welcome(){
        std :: cout << "------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        std :: cout << "  Welcome to Faculty Feedback form. Enter Your credentials\n";
        std :: cout << "------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    }
};

class Admin: public Design{

};

class Student: public Admin{

};

class Login: public Student{
    //bool a = true; Works fine
    bool a;
    a = true; // Shows error
    public:
    void authenticate(){

    }
};

int main(){
    Login LOGIN;
    LOGIN.welcome();
    LOGIN.authenticate();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a constructor. Classes and functions are different.

```
class Login: public Student{
    //bool a = true; Works fine
    bool a;
    Login() : a(true) 
    {
    }
    public:
    void authenticate(){

    }
};
```